# Is it possible to modify partitions of Android running Tablet?

Tags: partitioning, android

I have a Chinese tab and Probably its duplicate. The Model  reads:

SAMSUNG- N9106HD

The problem with the tab is it has two partitions of storage. One named as "Internal Storage" and another is "Phone Storage".[Storege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WLnp.jpg)
Internal Storage contains the Operating System (Android-4.4.2 kitkat) and all the applications. The size of this storage is only 2GB. Therefore it becomes full and no more apps can be installed. I tried moving some apps to the phone storage (30GB) but most of the apps don't move.
So, I want to have a fresh installation of Android and delete extra partition and make one partition of 32 GB.
Is it possible to do so? if yes, then how do I do so?

Comment: Do NOT try to do it, though I don't know if such a thing is possible, I know on a desktop PC it is very easy to do so, you can just delete the partitions and create a new partition and activate it using diskpart and install Windows to it using dism, it is really easy to do, and nothing will go wrong if you do it properly, however here we are talking about Android tablets, reinstalling Windows doesn't change BIOS/UEFI/Firmware, Android is embedded means you have to change the firmware, you need to flash the firmware first, and you need an Android ROM image specifically designed for your tablet

Comment: Or your tablet will become a glass brick, all of these are really complicated and need expert knowledge and experience, this is way more difficult than merely merging the partitions and installing Windows, the process is very likely to go wrong if used by newbies and once it goes wrong its consequence is disastrous, do not attempt to do it yourself